# Uncaught TypeError with AJAX when processing form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple contact form on my website that I'm hoping to send data with using AJAX/PHP.

When I hit the submit button, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mode' of undefined
    at Function.$.ajax (jquery.validate.js:1561)
    at submitForm (form-scripts.js:21)
```

Line 21 begins below:

**Code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/form-process.php",
    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
    success : function(text){
        if (text == "success"){
            formSuccess();
        } else {
            formError();
            submitMSG(false,text);
        }
    }
});
```

I am using jQuery 3.1.1 (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js) - perhaps this has something to do with it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Issue seems to be in jquery validate plugin not in the posted code.

Comment: @Jai Apologies - here it's for reference https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your using lite version of jquery which doesn't have jQuery.ajaxPrefilter but it is required by Jquery validate. So use this [cdn](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js)

Comment: Wow - amazing!!! That was it exactly. I would have bee there all day. Thank you, sir!