# Pass form value to PHP via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a script that uses AJAX to display results from a separate PHP script on my page.

However, now I'd like to pass data from the form (the **select** menu) to the script. How do I do this? I'd just like to use the value selected in the select menu as part of the WHERE clause in my SQL command.

---

**Web Page:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#display").click(function() {                

        $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
          type: "GET",
          url: "display.php",             
          dataType: "html",
          data: {
              "some-var": "some-value"
          },            
          success: function(response){                    
              $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
          }

        });

    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <select id="city" name="city">
  <option value="">City:</option>
  <option value="glasgow">Glasgow</option>
  <option value="london">London</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" id="display" value="Display All Data" />
</form>
<br>
<div id="responsecontainer">&nbsp;</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP script:**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM entries";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - City: " . $row["city"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Jquery `form.serialize()`. When will you start reading manuals?

Comment: serialize the form just @u_mulder said. You can also do this with jquery's FOrmData

Comment: `data:$('form').serialize()`, as @u_mulder have said

Comment: You did use ajax on here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450121/uncaught-typeerror-with-ajax-when-processing-form   how did u pass the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#display").click(function() {                

        $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
          type: "GET",
          url: "display.php",             
          dataType: "html",
          data: {
              "city": $('#city').val(),
          },            
          success: function(response){                    
              $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
          }

        });

    });
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I just had to add `$city = $_GET['city']; $sql = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE city = '$city'";` to my PHP. Many thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear that I helped.  ^^

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can get the value of the selected option:

```
$('#city').val()
```

So you can then send that with your ajax request:

```
$('#display').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "display.php",             
      data: {
          "city": $('#city').val()
      },            
      success: function(response){                    
          $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
      }

   });
});
```

Then in your PHP:

```
$city = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['city']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE city = '".$city."'";
```

N.B. You should be very careful about trusting user provided variables with queries.

Comment: Many thanks, Harry. I 100% agree - I will be passing user input data through some fairly strict filtering and validation tools now I have got the data I need. Thankyou :)